# How to fix aws amplify push casuing cloudformation errors saying UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I am stuck on what to do with this amplify push error. I made changes in `dev` and pushed to amplify and it worked. Then I merged the changes to `main` and pushed the `main` amplify environment, but this has now caused errors in the cloud formation templates that I cannot undo.

Here was the pre-push to `main`

```bash
⠸ Building resource api/myapp✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/me/Code/consulting_projects/tmt/myapp/amplify/backend/api/myapp/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/me/Code/consulting_projects/tmt/myapp/amplify/backend/api/myapp/schema
✔ Successfully pulled backend environment main from the cloud.
⠙ Building resource api/myapp✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/brymei/Code/consulting_projects/tmt/myapp/amplify/backend/api/myapp/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/me/Code/consulting_projects/tmt/myapp/amplify/backend/api/myapp/schema

    Current Environment: main
    
┌──────────┬────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Category │ Resource name                  │ Operation │ Provider plugin   │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Hosting  │ amplifyhosting                 │ Create    │                   │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ notificationapi                │ Update    │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ tmtamplifyapp                  │ Update    │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ notificationScheduledSender    │ Update    │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ scheduledDataCleaner           │ Update    │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ sendNotificationGo             │ Update    │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ AdminQueries                   │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Auth     │ tmtAmplifyApp                  │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ AdminQueries38301bfb           │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Storage  │ s3tmtamplifyappstoragec3cc73b4 │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
└──────────┴────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┘
✔ Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/n) · yes
✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/me/Code/consulting_projects/tmt/myapp/amplify/backend/api/myapp/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/me/Code/consulting_projects/tmt/myapp/amplify/backend/api/myapp/schema
⠏ Building resource api/tmtamplifyapp✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/me/Code/consulting_projects/tmt/myapp/amplify/backend/api/myapp/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/me/Code/consulting_projects/tmt/myapp/amplify/backend/api/myapp/schema
⚠️ Warning: You've specified "*" as the "Resource" in sendNotificationGo's custom IAM policy.
 This will grant sendNotificationGo the ability to perform ses:SendEmail,ses:SendRawEmail on ALL resources in this AWS Account.
⚠️ Warning: You've specified "*" as the "Resource" in sendNotificationGo's custom IAM policy.
 This will grant sendNotificationGo the ability to perform SNS:Publish on ALL resources in this AWS Account.
Deployment completed.

Rolled back (2 of 1)
 ["Index: 0 State: {\"deploy\":\"deploying\"} Message: Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:stack/amplify-tmtamplifyapp-main-183644-apitmtamplifyapp-1OB0VC3EYWXXH/44e74640-c1f1-11ed-b081-0aaebdb172df is in UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS state and can not be updated."]

Learn more at: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/

Session Identifier: ab7b4a94-753c-4623-b6b0-de4d34343860

✅ Report saved: /tmp/tmtAmplifyApp/report-1707071616199.zip

✔ Done
```

### Other attempts to fix it:

1. I have tried `amplify push --iterative-rollback` with no success.
2. I have given the amplify CICD role permissiong to Rollback Stacks
3. I have manually clicked `continue stack rollback` on the root stack, then tried to `amplify push` again.

I have seen other options of skipping resources when rolling back but that can get you into more issues. I have experience with Terraform but not with Cloudformation, and figuring out all the stacks and their events is not clear.

How can I untangle this? My production deployment is not frozen at this and I can't make any other changes to the backend.

### Other info:

[image]
[image]

I attempted to manually refresh the stack because I thought that the IAM role with Amplify didn't have enough permissions. That did allow me to run the amplify push again, but then the push failed after about 30 minutes.

[image: Screenshot from 2024-02-06 20-53-25]

[image]

Looking at the cloud formation templates, the core issue is that the template is trying to set up the /email route on the API gateway, but that doesn't exist anymore in the code. I've run the amplify remove function and amplify remove API to get rid of both the function and the API route from the code, but I cannot run amplify push successfully to remove this faulty stack. What can I do?

## Edits

Here is the deployment activity as shown in AWS Amplify. It is saying category: `amplify-tmtamplifyapp-main-183644` failed with `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` in red.

[image: amplify Console Stack Events]

This is the root stack set up by amplify

[image: Root Stack]

After clicking the `detect root cause` on the main stack, I get this information:

```bash
Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:818787344107:stack/amplify-tmtamplifyapp-main-183644-apinotificationapi-1OB5PIV17MKN/92641950-0d5c-11ee-bed8-0a20067762f3 was not successfully updated. Currently in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS with reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [notificationapi].
```

Going to the embedded stack, here are the most recent events for it:

[image: Embedded api notification api stack]

This stack says that it can't invalid lambda function for paths `/email` and `/email/{proxy+}`. This is because I deleted this API and function from my amplify project and they shoudn't be in the code base. So how do I delete/ rollback this api? `Amplify push` should be able to update this to delete this api and function.

## Edit 2

Here are the [cloudformation templates in github](https://github.com/Bryson14/code-snippets/tree/main/amplify-cloudformation-templates).

Following this error about having an invalid lambda function ARN, I created a new lambda function manually called `SendEmail-main` to mimic what the template was looking for. I then ran `amplify push` again with this hope that I can get the stack to deploy successfully and then I can change the backend normally again.

This was the slightly new failure message after running `amplify push`:

```bash
Deployment completed.
Deploying api tmtamplifyapp [ ===------------------------------------- ] 2/23
        GraphQLAPITransformerSchema3C… AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema    UPDATE_COMPLETE                Thu Feb 08 2024 21:46:03…     
        GraphQLAPIDefaultApiKey215A6D… AWS::AppSync::ApiKey           UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS             Thu Feb 08 2024 21:35:13…     

Rolled back (4 of 3)
 ["Index: 2 State: {\"deploy\":\"waitingForDeployment\"} Message: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete"]
```

Checking the cloud formation console, the main stack and notification nested stack have the read Update_rollback_complete. Both stack's resources have green update_complete status, but checking the events of the notification stack shows the same error message of invalid lambda function so it couldn't make the integration to the API resource.

### Edit 3

After running `amplify pull`, here are the results of `amplify status -v`

```bash
Current Environment: main
```

| Category | Resource name | Operation | Provider plugin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hosting | amplifyhosting | Create |  |
| Api | AdminQueries | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Api | notificationapi | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Api | tmtamplifyapp | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Auth | tmtAmplifyApp | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Function | AdminQueries38301bfb | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Function | notificationScheduledSender | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Function | scheduledDataCleaner | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Function | sendNotificationGo | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Storage | s3tmtamplifyappstoragec3cc73b4 | No Change | awscloudformation |

```bash
[➥] Resource Stack: Hosting/amplifyhosting : Create
No changes
```

### Edit 4

> wow never thought I'd be in this deep. smh

So I went to the amplify console to see the last successfully deployed cicd pipeline. It was at `HEAD~3`. I `git revert <success_commit>` to that and tried to run `amplify push` just to get cloudformation to work with me. I expected this to work. But it appears that amplify cli thinks no change is going to happen, but then cfn state is different, hence why running `amplify pull` brings in new code.

```bash
amplify push 
⠴ Fetching updates to backend environment: main from the cloud.✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/me/Code/consulting/tmt/tmtAmplifyApp/amplify/backend/api/tmtamplifyapp/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/me/Code/consulting/tmt/tmtAmplifyApp/amplify/backend/api/tmtamplifyapp/schema
✔ Successfully pulled backend environment main from the cloud.

    Current Environment: main
    
┌──────────┬────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Category │ Resource name                  │ Operation │ Provider plugin   │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Hosting  │ amplifyhosting                 │ Create    │                   │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ AdminQueries                   │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ notificationapi                │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ tmtamplifyapp                  │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Auth     │ tmtAmplifyApp                  │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ AdminQueries38301bfb           │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ notificationScheduledSender    │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ scheduledDataCleaner           │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ sendNotificationGo             │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Storage  │ s3tmtamplifyappstoragec3cc73b4 │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
└──────────┴────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┘
✔ Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/n) · yes
⠹ Building resource api/tmtamplifyapp✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/me/Code/consulting/tmt/tmtAmplifyApp/amplify/backend/api/tmtamplifyapp/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/me/Code/consulting/tmt/tmtAmplifyApp/amplify/backend/api/tmtamplifyapp/schema

Deployment failed.
Deploying root stack tmtAmplifyApp [ =================================------- ] 9/11
        amplify-tmtamplifyapp-main-18… AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE       Sat Feb 10 2024 12:34:55…     
        storages3tmtamplifyappstorage… AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_COMPLETE                Sat Feb 10 2024 12:31:41…     
        authtmtAmplifyApp              AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_COMPLETE                Sat Feb 10 2024 12:31:41…     
        functionAdminQueries38301bfb   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_COMPLETE                Sat Feb 10 2024 12:31:42…     
        apitmtamplifyapp               AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_COMPLETE                Sat Feb 10 2024 12:32:59…     
        apiAdminQueries                AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_COMPLETE                Sat Feb 10 2024 12:31:53…     
        functionsendNotificationGo     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_COMPLETE                Sat Feb 10 2024 12:33:21…     
        functionscheduledDataCleaner   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_COMPLETE                Sat Feb 10 2024 12:33:21…     
        functionnotificationScheduled… AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_COMPLETE                Sat Feb 10 2024 12:33:21…     
        apinotificationapi             AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_FAILED                  Sat Feb 10 2024 12:31:37…     

 The following resources failed to deploy:
Resource Name: notificationapi (AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi)
Event Type: update
Reason: Resource handler returned message: "Errors found during import:
        Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/capturePaypal/{orderID}': Invalid lambda function
        Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/capturePaypal/{orderID}/{proxy+}': Invalid lambda function
        Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/email': Invalid lambda function
        Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/email/{proxy+}': Invalid lambda function (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 8c426837-6838-4231-81c6-d0e8fd7ac427)" (RequestToken: 494a8460-1dbc-7ede-2b65-c6aec655039a, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
URL: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A818787344107%3Astack%2Famplify-tmtamplifyapp-main-183644-apinotificationapi-1OB5PIV17MKN%2F92641950-0d5c-11ee-bed8-0a20067762f3/events


 Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
Name: notificationapi (AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi), Event Type: update, Reason: Resource handler returned message: "Errors found during import:
        Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/capturePaypal/{orderID}': Invalid lambda function
        Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/capturePaypal/{orderID}/{proxy+}': Invalid lambda function
        Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/email': Invalid lambda function
        Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/email/{proxy+}': Invalid lambda function (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 8c426837-6838-4231-81c6-d0e8fd7ac427)" (RequestToken: 494a8460-1dbc-7ede-2b65-c6aec655039a, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest), IsCustomResource: false
```

right now it appears that there is a current rollback state that cloudformation is stuck in. Amplify is keeping its version of state in the s3 bucket and a version in my computer. If i had to guess at this point, both version of amplify's state (local and s3) do not reflect what is in the cfn templates, so the `email` function is never made, and the API fails to update.

Comment: The notification-api itself should be ok - cloudformation can handle the failed creation of apigw integration, it'll just rollback to previous state of apigw. The thing your stack is complaining about is the nested stack. Can you show the state of the resources on the nested one (cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:stack/amplify-tmtamplifyapp-main-183644-apitmtamplifyapp-1OB0VC3EYWXXH/44e74640-c1f1-11ed-b081-0aaebdb172df)? What is it trying to delete/rollback?

Comment: Sorry, copied the id from the console log you gave and it is different in the screens - probably there was a push in between... I mean the one that the root stack points out in the "embedded stack... in update_complete_rollback_in_progress state" message

Comment: I tried to navigate the cloud formation console. I showed the embedded stack that is highlighted as the 'root cause'

Comment: Ok, from the screenshots I get that now both the nested and parent stacks are in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state, right? If not (if any of them are still IN_PROGRESS), you'd want to go to Resources tab on the stack and see what resource it is stuck on.

Comment: If both are in rollback_complete, then the problem should be in the template. When you run notify_push, a CF template for the nested (an then parent) stack is uploaded, and the stack is updated accoring to the diff between old and new templates. Can you go to the templates for both stacks (stack in CF console => template tab) and search for that problematic lambda integration? It must have been left somewhere in the code that generates the template. Or share the templates if it's not confidential

Comment: i can see from both of the "Stack into" tab the read `update roll back complete" but then clicking on both of their resource tabs, all the resources show "update complete" or "create complete". I added the link to see the main and notification APIs

Comment: Additionally, If i update one of the templates to take out the lambda function that shouldn't exist, can i update that template directly or is this a big NO-NO with nested stacks / CFN?

Comment: You can update the template manually, yes, but it will only help until next amplify push, since it will generate the faulty template again, upload it, and deploy the resources again... I personally only do that if I want to test out a small change an I don't want to wait for a build or click around in console too much (like renaming something, or pointing an api method to a different lambda)

Comment: Ok, I think I can see the part of the template that makes it go look for a non-existent lambda, it's the RestApi definition that still contains 2 non-mock integrations that point to `functionsendNotificationGoArn` lambda (I don't know what it is called for real, but you'll be able to tell by looking at "parameters" in the CF stack - that'll show you the arn). The methods are /notify and /notify/{proxy+}. I think you managed to delete the lambda but not the api path. The "proxy+" one is default, btw, so you might have overlooked it... What did you pass to "amplify api remove"?

Comment: Actually, sorry, I misread - you said you wanted to delete the `email` lambda/path, not the notify one. But the only lambda integration in that stack template you uploaded is the /notify one. That makes me think that what you are pushing is different and still contains the /email path (an then it rolls back to the template without it). Does running `amplify pull` and then `amplify status -v` locally show the email api?

Comment: Something I'm trying to find is the `/email` across my code base to see if that is in the S3  deployment bucket set up amplify or if it in my current version of main. Looking into github search, i see that the route `/email` and its function are defined at `origin/HEAD`, but that is not the same code I when running `amplify pull`. I hoped that by trying to push `HEAD` or `HEAD~1` to amplify, it would fix this issue and overwrite the existing templates, but both of those `push`es have led to the same error. `waitingForDeployment, Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete"]`

Comment: Oh. Do you know amplify has it's own "git-like" thing that is happening in the background? That might be the whole issue. Here is a pretty similar case described: https://dev.to/yonatankorem/if-you-use-amplify-and-git-branches-you-are-going-to-have-a-bad-time-4ck6

Comment: thanks for all your help and being a guide through this!

Comment: I think if that's the case, your best bet is to manually (through AWS console) get the stack to exactly the state that matches your `origin` branch (you might get luck with "detect drift" option, though I find it sometimes misses stuff, especially custom resources... but for lambda+apigw it should work). Then manually redeploy the stack in CF (use the update/retry/continue button there, not amplify-push) so it gets to green "updated" state. And then do what you wanted to do, keeping the branch mess in mind (so probably switch to master, cherry pick your new stuff, amplify push)

Comment: I see you got it to work:) Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

After all of this, I found out how to fix this in my case.

The problem arises when there are inconsistencies between the local version of your code and the version stored in the S3 bucket associated with your AWS account. AWS Amplify maintains two records of state: one in your local development environment and another in the S3 bucket, which should reflect what is deployed in the cloud formation. In my case, what was deployed to cloud formation was different than both the cloud and local state files, so running `amplify push` would apply just a partial diff change to the CFN template, but this partial change would lead to errored templates, and then cloud formation would rollback.

To resolve this issue:

1. **Synchronize Local and S3 Versions:**
   Start by running the `amplify pull` command. This will synchronize the local version of your code with the version stored in the S3 bucket.
2. **Forcefully Apply Changes:**
   Instead of relying on the default behavior of `amplify push`, which only applies change sets, use the `--force` flag. Use discretion as it may cause damage to your infrastructure, but it shouldn't cause loss of data in the dynamo tables. [amplify force push docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/tools/cli/project/troubleshooting/#:%7E:text=Scenario%202%3A%20%22amplify%20push%22%20fails%20after%20unmanaged%20updates%20to%20non%2Ddatabase%20resources%20in%20the%20cloud.)

I hope this helps resolve your issue and provides clarity so you don't have to struggle a whole week on production environment issues!

Additional help for managing git branches and amplify environments [article](https://dev.to/yonatankorem/if-you-use-amplify-and-git-branches-you-are-going-to-have-a-bad-time-4ck6)